# PHP random numbers frequency of occurrence

Tags: php, random

In PHP I want to generate random numbers from 1 to 10 in a loop.

So for example:

```
$factor="1"; // this will be changed in another area

for ($i=0;$i<10;$i++) {
if ($factor=="1") {$output = rand(1,10);}
else if ($factor=="2") {$output = rand(1,10);}
else {$output = rand(1,10);}

 }
```

Now to explain this - In result I want to receive 10 random numbers, but when `$factor = "2"`, in that case I want to receive numbers from **6 to 10 more frequently** as lower numbers.

It means, from 10 numbers I need to have 80% higher random numbers (it means larger than 5) and in 20% lower numbers (5 or lower).

E.g. 1,2,6,7,8,9,7,9,8,6  (1,2 are the only lower numbers = 20%, the rest are higher = 80)

If the `$factor` will change, then I want to change the percentage, in that case for example 40% lower numbers, 60% higher numbers.

The idea I have is to put each output in the loop to an array, then check each result and somehow calculate, if there is no 80% of larger numbers, then get random numbers again for those, but this seems to be an overkill.

Is there a simplier solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came with a very simple (maybe creepy) solution, but this works as I wanted:

```
echo print_r(generate("2"));

function generate($factor) {

$nums=array();

for ($i=0;$i<10;$i++) {
    
    if ($i<$factor) {$rnd = rand(1,5);}
    else {$rnd = rand(6,10);}

    array_push($nums,$rnd);
   
     } 
     return $nums;
    }
```

I can also shuffle the final array results, as the lower numbers will be on the beginning always, but in my case it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Let's go with the percentages you mention and first generate a random number between 1 and 100. Then the lower number, 1 to 20, have to represent outputs 1 to 5 and the higher numbers, 21 to 100, have to represent output 6 to 10. In PHP that would look like this:

```
function HighMoreOften()
{
    $percentage = rand(1, 100);
    if ($percentage <= 20) {
        return rand(1, 5);
    } else {
        return rand(6, 10);
    }
}
```

That should do the trick. You can also convert the percentage you got into the output, this would probably be slightly faster:

```
function HighMoreOften()
{
    $percentage = rand(1, 100);
    if ($percentage <= 20) {
        return ceil($percentage / 5);
    } else {
        return 6 + ceil(($percentage - 20) / 20);
    }
}
```

but personally I think the first version is easier to understand and change.

Comment: that has a good logic, but what if the result of percentage  will be in theory 30-40 times lower than 20? It is random, of course there is a chance more for a higher number, but it doesn't guarantee that it can't be 30 times lower then 20

Comment: I tried it and in a loop from 10 attempts it generated also this: 4, 8, 2, 9, 7, 2, 1, 7, 1, 8,and there are already 5 lower numbers which is much more than 20%

Comment: @Darksymphony: The more numbers you generate the closer the 20% will be approached, this is a basic quality of [stochasticity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic). If you want a guaranteed number below 6 you need to generate an array of numbers, with that property, and then randomize that array.

Comment: well that is what I want - from numbers 1-10 always to have 80% larger than 5, and the rest should be 5 or lower. E.g. 1,2,6,7,8,9,7,6,9,8. But I agree, I can't generate it by one number 10 times, will do it in array. However thank you for your solution and ideas. Btw. I updated my question to be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

To change frequency you gonna need an array of numbers. And a sum to this direction. frequency is the relation of something between an array of things.

```
$t = 0;

// $factor = 1; // let's say that this means 20%
$factor = 2; // let's say that this means 40%


 if ($factor === 1) { 
     
     for ($i = 1; $i <= 80; $i++) {
         $t += rand(1,10);
     }
     for ($i = 1; $i <= 20; $i++) {
         $t += rand(6,10);
     }

 } else if ($factor === 2) {
     
     for ($i = 1; $i <= 60; $i++) {
         $t += rand(1,10);
     }
     for ($i = 1; $i <= 40; $i++) {
         $t += rand(6,10);
     }
     
  
 } else {
     for ($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++) {
         $t += rand(1,10);
     }
 }
 echo round(($t/100), 0);
```

Something like that! :)